# UI in Xcode (Swift): I only want the collapsing functionality of UIStackView, not standardised spacing. Still worth using one?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimageview, uistackview

I have a UITableViewCell, in which I'd like to have two UILabels, a UIImageView, followed by a UIButton beneath (all stacked vertically). Diagrammatically, it would look like this:

```
UILabel

1 point vertical spacing

UILabel2

6 points vertical spacing

UImageView

4 points vertical spacing

UIButton
```

Any **two** of these may not be present (except the two labels), and the rest must resize accordingly, collapsing the empty space. Would a UIStackView be worth using here, keeping in mind that custom spacing would need to be used.

As an example, in a stack view, the UIImageView could be easily collapsed if we did not have an image to show, whereas without one, I can't think of a way of doing it without messing about with height constraints of the UIImageView in code. Perhaps this can be achieved with hiding the  UIImageView?

What approach would you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIStackView handles hiding / un-hiding views very well and lets the non-hidden elements take up any extra space. Would highly recommend using a UIStackView in this scenario. Custom spacing is no big deal, and can be accomplished like this:

`stackView.setCustomSpacing(6, after: UILabel2)`